# Erro quando executo teste do Scalatra no Intellij

Tags: testes, intellij-idea, scala

Estou tentando executar o seguinte teste do [scalatra](/questions/tagged/scalatra) dentro do [intellij](/questions/tagged/intellij):

```
class Test extends ScalatraFlatSpec with Matchers {
  addServlet(classOf[MainServlet], "/*")

  "Home Page" should "show hello" in {
    get("/"){
      status should equal (200);
    }
  }
}
```

E a IDE esta me retornando o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
  at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateInstanceMethods(MethodValidator.java:32)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateMethodsForDefaultRunner(MethodValidator.java:43)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.validate(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:36)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:27)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
  at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.buildRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
  at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
```

Answer (score 2):

Obtive este mesmo erro quando estava executando como teste do [java](/questions/tagged/java) e não como teste do [scala](/questions/tagged/scala).

Nem sempre o [intellij](/questions/tagged/intellij) acerta o tipo correto de teste.

Se este for o caso para corrigir troque de:

[image: Teste do Junit]

Para:

[image: Teste do ScalaTest]

E o teste vai executar corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]